# How to limit SMTP delivery to hourly batches

Tags: iis-6, smtp, connection, limit, outbound

In an effort to keep us from being labeled spammers by major ISPs (in addition to SPF records, privacy policies, CANSPAM compliance and the like) - I wanted to limit the amount of mail we send out an hour.
Is this possible in W2K3 SMTP server?  I was looking at outbound connection properties in the SMTP virtual server config screens...It's just not that clear if tinkering with those settings are going to do what I want.

In a nutshell, I'd love mail being sent by this server to queue up and send for example, 5,000 messages every 10 minutes or so.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think this should go under serverfault.com

Comment: Is that a more appropriate place?

Answer (score 2):

So, I found out what I wanted - in case others look for it.
I'm using the config settings for ASPNET to drop the mail into a different pickup directory on the server (rather than the default Queue directory). Then I can simply use a scheduled task to check the pickup directory every 30 minutes or so and copy N number of messages to the SMTP Queue directory...Where they will be picked up and mailed.  The configuration section/settings is:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
          <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\YOUR_CUSTOM_PICKUP_DIR" />
        </smtp>  
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you suign to send the mail, As far as i know i dont think you can set the sending server, But if you have some code which puts the mail together you could just put the send function on a timer.

5000 email every 10 mins is still going to get you marked as SPAM though after a few days. as thats close to 1 million emails a day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Mail is being sent via ASP.Net. Also, I wouldn't be sending 1 million a day. Probably 30,000 tops - and doing that only a few times a month. I'm just trying to avoid a tidal wave of 30k going out in 1 minute and setting off every network spam monitoring alarm in North America. I know I could do it with a combination console app / scheduled job. My question was if there was an easier way to accomplish this with the Virtual SMTP Server settings on Win2k3.